# Hide video source src from html by video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm using [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) in my project.  What I'm trying to do is hide the video source from the html tag.

I've tried to set up the src from js code as following:

```
var videoPlayer = videojs("videoPlayerLive", {
    "controls": true,
    "autoplay": false,
    "preload": "none",
});

videoPlayer.src('some url');
```

Still I can find the `src` in the video tag if I check the video player element from Chrome.  (From Chrome, right click the video player and select `Inspect`, I can find the html element with the src there.)

Does anybody know how to hide this `src` attribute from the html?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could make it more difficult to retrieve the source by using a javascript obfuscation tool.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Hi thanx for your suggestion.  But what I'm trying to do here is to hide the src='some url' from the html.

Comment: Well, you cant hide it, there are just some tweaks you can do to make it more difficult to inspect the source.

Comment: There [are ways to hide the attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/hbncwcua/1/), but one will still be able to open its console's *Network* Panel and see from where it comes. Or even, to read your js.

So all in all, it's a no-go.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you.  I understand it's impossible to completely hide the source.  I only want to hide the attribute, so will give the page a little bit protection.  You mentioned there are ways to do this.  I tried your code, but it not work.  Would you please share more explanation?  Many thanx.

Comment: @Vigor it should work in both latests ff and chrome, but yes, it uses some quite new APIs. But anyway, this was just a demo of "everything is possible" but in no way one should do this. It's just useless and makes things harder for you, not for a potential attacker.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
`Inspect` will show the whole content including **dynamically** loaded.

What you see in the browser can be seen by `inspecting`. Where as `view-source` show only **static content**.
You can `uglify` the js source code to prevent users from viewing the url. But still they can get it by using `getAttribute` in the console.